# if condition is not working properly as i am getting value of variable as undefined

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I am running a neo4j cypher query in nodejs and getting the results in callback function:

```
async (body) => {

    await query.cypher({
            query: 'Match (phoneno {phnnumber : {number}}) return phoneno',
            params: {
                number: body
            }
        },
        await
        function(err, data) {
            len = data.length
            console.log("len:" + len)

        });
    console.log("len outside:" + len)

    if (len == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The "len outside:" console log and the `if` statement both show that `len` is `undefined`. Can anyone see why?

Comment: Make sure you use labels in your Cypher match! In its current form `phoneno` is a variable without a label, so this will perform an all nodes scan, a very expensive operation. You should add the label of the node in question, and probably have an index on the label/property combination for fast lookup.

Comment: Which neo4j client package are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should define `len` as a variable at the top of the function:

```
async(body)=>{
    var len = null;

        await query.cypher({
            query: 'Match (phoneno {phnnumber : {number}}) return phoneno',
            params: {
                number : body
            }
        },
        await function(err,data){
         len = data.length
         console.log("len:"+len)

        });
        console.log("len outside:"+len)

        if (len == 0 ){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
}
```